# MySQLIntegrityConstraintException - “Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails” in Grails

Tags: grails

Am trying to get some order information from XML file and trying to store it in database(MySQL) table. I can retrieve the order information from XML file but when am trying to insert into the table it shows error as MySQLIntegrityConstraintException.

My program contains as below,

`def Order = new XmlParser().parse("MyXml.xml")`
`def set1 = sql.dataSet("order_item")`
`def set2 = sql.dataSet("order_header")`
`Order.order_item.each {`
`// retrieving order information and storing`
`}`
`set1.add(Column_Name1:order_id,Column_Name2:field2,Column_Name3:field3)`
`set2.add(Column_Name1:order_id)`

I listed the error in detail below

> WARNING: Failed to execute: insert into order_item (order_id, order_item_seq_id,
>    order_item_type_id, product_id, prod_catalog_id, quantity, unit_price, unit_lis
>   t_price, item_description, status_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) beca
>   use: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ecommerc
>   e/order_item`, CONSTRAINT `ORDER_ITEM_HDR` FOREIGN KEY (`ORDER_ID`) REFERENCES 
>   `order_header` (`ORDER_ID`))
>   Caught: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationExcepti
>   on: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ecommerce
>   /order_item`, CONSTRAINT `ORDER_ITEM_HDR` FOREIGN KEY (`ORDER_ID`) REFERENCES `o
>   rder_header` (`ORDER_ID`))
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cann
>   ot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ecommerce/order_i
>   tem`, CONSTRAINT `ORDER_ITEM_HDR` FOREIGN KEY (`ORDER_ID`) REFERENCES `order_hea
>   der` (`ORDER_ID`))
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:384)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1041)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3562)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3494)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1960)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2114)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2696)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.ja
>   va:2105)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java
>   :2398)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java
>   :2316)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java
>   :2301)
>           at db2xml.XMLToDatabase$_main_closure2.doCall(XMLToDatabase.groovy:52)
>           at db2xml.XMLToDatabase.main(XMLToDatabase.groovy:38)

Can anyone help me to come out from this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: looks like you are trying to add an order_id that does not exist in your database, hence making your foreign key check fail.

Comment: but what happens by default is order_id is generated automatically by the application since am integrating this as an api with the application how to handle this

Comment: your gorm objects are not modelling your db correctly.  you may want to look at the reverse db engineering plugin

Comment: @ Chrislovecnm.. So you mean that i want to use some database plugin separately to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first the foreign key constraint table to be updated initially then the specific table to should me updated. A small change in the above code is

`set2.add(Column_Name1:order_id)`
`set1.add(Column_Name1:order_id,Column_Name2:field2,Column_Name3:field3)`

The set 2 should updated first and then the set 1.

Now it got worked for me. Thanks for all.